# Return all records with a balance below a threshold value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to setup a query to return all order line items with an outstanding balance below a certain threshold value (5%, for example). I managed this query without any concerns, but there is a complication. I only want to return these line items in cases where there aren't any line items outside of this threshold.

For example, if line item 1 has an Ordered Qty of 100, and 98 have been received, this line item would be returned *unless* there is a line item 2 with an Order qty of 100 and 50 received (since this is above the 5% threshold).

This might be more easily demonstrated than explained, so I set up a simplified SQL Fiddle to show what I have thus far. I'm using a CTE to add a remaining balance field and then querying against that within my threshold. I appreciate any advice

In the fiddle example, OrderNum 987654 should NOT be returned since that order has a second line item with 50% remaining.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1a7076/1)

```
;WITH cte as (
  SELECT 
   h.OrderNum
  ,d.ItemNumber
  ,d.OrderedQty
  ,d.ReceivedQty
  ,100.0 * (1 - (CAST(d.ReceivedQty as Numeric(10, 2)) / d.OrderedQty)) as RemainingBal
  FROM OrderHeader h
  INNER JOIN OrderDetail d
  ON h.OrderNum = d.OrderNum
)

SELECT * FROM Cte 
WHERE RemainingBal >0 and RemainingBal <= 5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work...

```
  ;WITH cte as (
  SELECT 
   h.OrderNum
  ,d.ItemNumber
  ,d.OrderedQty
  ,d.ReceivedQty
  ,100.0 * (1 - (CAST(d.ReceivedQty as Numeric(10, 2)) / d.OrderedQty)) as 
  RemainingBal
  FROM OrderHeader h
  INNER JOIN OrderDetail d
  ON h.OrderNum = d.OrderNum
 )
 SELECT * FROM Cte WHERE OrderNum IN(
 SELECT OrderNum
 FROM Cte
 GROUP BY OrderNum
 HAVING CAST((SUM(OrderedQty)) - (SUM(ReceivedQty)) AS 
 DECIMAL(10,2))/CAST(SUM(OrderedQty) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) <= .05
)
```